# Найти отстутствующий в последовательности номер

Tags: linux, bash, perl, sed, awk

После работы некоторого скрипта, в файл записывается примерно следующее:

```
1 ---> something
2 ---> something
3 ---> something
...
18254 --> something
```

Бывает такое, что в виду того, что я использую в скрипте старый добрый eval, который помогает мне, чтобы прога не упала на какой-либо ошибке, то какой-нибудь запрос (пусть это будет 4205) может не записаться в файл:

Покажу на примере:

```
...
4200 ---> something
4201 ---> something
4202 ---> something
4203 ---> something
4204 ---> something
4206 ---> something
```

Вопрос: как проверить, какого номера строки (или просто, какого номера нет в файле) нет в файле? И возможно ли?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать как-то так:

```
awk -v var="$((`head -n 1 file | awk '{print $1}'`))" 'BEGIN {p=var} {for(i=p+1; i<$1; i++) print i} {p=$1}' file
```

Результат будет:

```
4205
```

- Сначала мы забираем первое число, которое у нас есть в файле. Если этого не делать, то счет будет с 1. Просто у вас из вопроса не ясно, с какого числа начинается счет.
- Потом через awk мы просто проверяем последовательность чисел. И если числа нет, то выводим его на экран.

Для случая, если **ВСЕГДА** последовательность чисел начинается с 1

```
awk '{for(i=p+1; i<$1; i++) print i} {p=$1}' file
```

Comment: ну, строка 1 = число 1 и так далее...

Comment: @misdeed Я тогда добавил более простой вариант для файла, который всегда начинается с 1

Answer (score 4):

```
seq $(grep -oP '^\d+' input.txt | tail -1) | diff - <(grep -oP '^\d+' input.txt) | grep '<'
```

- Сперва находим последнюю пронумерованную строку *(grep -oP '^\d+' input.txt | tail -1)*
- Далее создаем последовательность без потери чисел *(seq см.предыдущее)*
- Сравниваем полученную последовательность с той, что имеется в файле *(см. предыдущее | diff - <(grep -oP '^\d+' input.txt)*
- Выводим отсутствующие числа *(см. предыдущее | grep '<')*

Команду *grep -oP '^\d+' input.txt* можно вывести в переменную, чтобы не тратиться на повторное чтение данных из файла.
В случае поиска отсутствия диапазонов чисел лучше использовать *awk*.

**Дополнение**

```
# заносим номера строк в переменную
n=($(grep -oP '^\d+' input.txt))
# выводим различия целочисленных последовательностей
echo $(seq ${n[-1]}) ${n[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n | uniq -u
```